# How to load RX source in vs2013?

Tags: system.reactive, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols, pdb-files

I am trying to debug into the RX source. 
Does anyone know where the pdb for RX is located? Google and SymbolSource failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, pdbs aren't shipped. However, since the code is open source, you could build your own. The source lives at https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET.

I [raised an issue](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/89) asking for symbol files to be shipped.

Comment: Incidentally, I have used [Redgate Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)  Pro version's functionality to dynamically create PDB's over decompiled source to debug Rx in the past. Nowhere near as good as the original pdbs would be, but it has been helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I have now resorted to Reflector too, would be better with pdbs though...no license